# Press any key to exit in command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, autohotkey

I have an autohotkey script that runs cmd to check the hash for the selected file.
I use certutil command for that task.

```
#h::
      hwnd := WinExist("A")
      for Window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows  
          if (window.hwnd==hwnd) {
              Selection := Window.Document.SelectedItems
              for Items in Selection
                  Path_to_Selection := Items.path
          }
run %ComSpec% /k certutil -hashfile "%Path_to_Selection%" md5
return
```

I want the cmd screen shows "press any key to exit" or anything similar after the script is completed, so I can easily close the window via any key, not just alt + f4 or clicking on X button. any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running CMD in order to execute the `certutil` command,
use instead this command in the script:

```
run "path\to\batch.bat" "%Path_to_Selection%"
```

The `.bat` file will contain these commands :

```
certutil -hashfile "%1" md5
pause Press any key to exit
```

Comment: wow!! works like charm. thank you trillion ton! I wonder why this can't be implemented with the use of command parameters though.